# Set default language english for android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

How I can set default language English for EditText in android?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I think if your app is english by default it automatically does it.  If I'm not right then edit text just has characters not language.

Answer (score 0):

t's not possible to change the keyboard settings for the user programmatically. The only thing you can do is advise the user to change it and help it to do so. For instance, this will show a dialog for them to change keyboard:

```
private void showInputMethodPicker() {
    InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    if (imeManager != null) {
        imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_possible_im_picker, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```